# Ruby on Rails: Validate the number of times a user enters a word on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

In my RoR application, I want to stop users repeating a specific word in a text area on a form. I have a form that allows users to enter text to send in an email, and I want to stop them from saying the word "var1" more than once. Is this possible?

I have tried to do so using the following validation in my model, but this does not work:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    has_many :recipients
    has_many :contacts, through: :recipients, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :groups, through: :recipients, :dependent => :destroy

    validate :singular_var1

    private
    def singular_var1
        if message.scan(/"var1"/).length > 1
            errors.add :message, 'You must not repeat the word VAR1'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a regex, you just need to remove the quotations:

```
...

if message.scan(/var1/).length > 1
  errors.add :message, 'You must not repeat the word VAR1'
end

...
```

However, keep in mind that the way you're currently using it, it will only capture lowercase "var1", not mixed case, or uppercase. If you want it to capture any casing variation, do this instead:

```
...

if message.downcase.scan(/var1/).length > 1
  errors.add :message, 'You must not repeat the word VAR1'
end

...
```